# Python multidimensional array fast access?

Tags: php, python

In php I can have an array

```
$shop["rose"] = array(1 , 15);
$shop["jim"] = array( 5 , 7);
$shop["bud"] = array( 9 , 22);
```

If I type $shop["jim"] I get the array for Jim.
How could I do this in Python?

Thanks
Glenn

Comment: What have you tried? SO, isn't really a code translation service.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lists and Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in Python in order to use the same strategy:

```
shop = {
    'rose': [1,15],
    'jim': [5,7],
    'bud': [9,22]
}

print(shop)         # {'rose': [1, 15], 'jim': [5, 7], 'bud': [9, 22]}
print(shop['rose']) # [1, 15]
```